# I'm having an if-statement issue

Tags: java, eclipse

I already written the program and ran it but I don't know how to prevent both println statements to show up when I run it with an invalid digit. It's basically a program in which you input the month & day (in numerical value) and the output would be the season. Here's the code:

```
public class Solstice {
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    int month;
    int day;
    String season = "seasons";

    System.out.println("Enter a month: ");
    month = in.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter a day: ");
    day = in.nextInt();

    String winter = "winter";
    String spring = "spring";
    String summer = "summer";
    String fall = "fall";

    System.out.println("Month="+ month +" Day= "+day);


    if (month <= 3)
    {
        season = winter;
    }
    else if (month <= 6)
    {
        season = spring;
    }
    else if (month <= 9)
    {
        season = summer;
    }
    else if (month <= 12)
    {
        season = fall;
    } else {
        System.out.println("The value is invalid.");
    }

    System.out.println(season);
    }
}
```

Comment: You could initialize `season` to null, and not print it if null.

Answer (score 2):

write:

```
String season = null;
```

and then check before the last if:

```
if(season == null){
    //print invalid
} else {
    //print corresponding season
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way could be:

```
boolean invalid = false;

if (month <= 3)
{
    season = winter;
}
else if (month <= 6)
{
    season = spring;
}
else if (month <= 9)
{
    season = summer;
}
else if (month <= 12)
{
    season = fall;
} else {
    invalid = true;
}

if(invalid){
    System.out.println("The value is invalid.");
} else {
    System.out.println(season);
}
```

The only thing you have to do is to remember whether the date was invalid. Therefore, you need a boolean flag `invalid`.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be test as follows. Otherwise you would set a true false flag and test it at the end to determine what to print. Note that system is set to invalid as a default and therefore the error printout would be
    season is invalid

Another way of doing this would be a switch statement with the appropriate cases and setting the default to make season invalid. That way one would not need to do all the elseif statements. However, I am showing the if elseif in order to keep it like the original question.

```
System.out.println("Enter a month: ");
month = in.nextInt();

System.out.println("Enter a day: ");
day = in.nextInt();

String winter = "winter";
String spring = "spring";
String summer = "summer";
String fall = "fall";
String invalid = "invalid";
String season = invalid; // Set the default to invalid

System.out.println("Month="+ month +" Day= "+day);

if (month > 12 || month < 1)
{
    season = invalid;
}
elseif (month > 9)
{
    season = fall;
} 
if (month > 6)
{
    season = summer;
}
else if (month > 3)
{
    season = spring;
}
else
{
    season = winter;
}
System.out.println("season is ", season);
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the `season` to `null`, and check for `null` before printing. Remove the last `else`

```
if (season != null) {
    System.out.println(season);
} else {
    System.out.println("The value is invalid.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to encapsulate the if statements. You will not need to work with `null`. And you will only get output for valid seasons.

```
if (month > 12 || month < 1)
{
    season = invalid;
} else {
    if (month > 9)
    {
        season = fall;
    } 
    else if (month > 6)
    {
        season = summer;
    }
    else if (month > 3)
    {
        season = spring;
    }
    else
    {
        season = winter;
    }
    System.out.println("season is ", season);
}
```